# Как получить имя созданной и нажатой кнопки?

Tags: c#

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    LinkLabel llb = new LinkLabel();
    llb.Parent = this;
    llb.Text = i.ToString();

    // Имя созданной кнопки

    llb.Click += new EventHandler(linklabel);
}

public void linklabel(object obj, EventArgs ea)
{
    // Имя нажатой кнопки
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
llb.Name
```

или

```
((LinkLabel)obj).Name
```